# why the stored procedure not work and showbox "incorrect syntax near ')'. "

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.storMember
(
    @Check nchar          (1),
    @UserName nvarchar    (15),
    @Passowerd nvarchar   (15)=null,
    @Name nvarchar        (15)=null,
    @Phone nvarchar       (15)=null,
    @email nvarchar       (30)=null,
    @CompanyName nvarchar (15)=null ,
    @Gender nvarchar      (15)=null,
    @BarthDay date        (15)=null,
    @Question nvarchar    (15)=null,
    @answer nvarchar      (100)=null,
)
AS
   IF @check = 'a' 
   BEGIN
      INSERT INTO Member
      VALUES(@Check, @UserName, @Passowerd, @Name, @Phone, @email, 
             @CompanyName, @Gender, @BarthDay, @Question, @answer)
   END 

   IF @Check = 'u'
   BEGIN
      UPDATE Member
      SET          
          Passowerd = @Passowerd, [Name] = @Name, Phone = @Phone,
          email = @email, CompanyName = @CompanyName, 
          Gender = @Gender, BarthDay = @BarthDay, 
          Question = @Question, Answer = @Answer
      WHERE 
          (UserName = @UserName)
   END

   IF @check= 'd' 
   BEGIN
      DELETE FROM member 
      WHERE (userName = @userName)
   END

   RETURN
```

Comment: At first you must read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: also try cleaning up the code and making it more readable you should use `Default Parameters personally to handle your Insert / Update/ or Delete commands`

Comment: If you use `@Check NCHAR(1)`, then you should also make sure to check against a Unicode character! Use `IF @Check = N'a'` - the `N` prefix indicates a **Unicode** character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a surplus comma here:

```
@answer nvarchar      (100)=null,
)
```

also `check`isn't a good column name as it is a reserved keyword, and the `date`type doesn't take a size parameter.

This should work:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.storMember 
( 
    @Check nchar (1), 
    @UserName nvarchar (15), 
    @Passowerd nvarchar (15)=null, 
    @Name nvarchar (15)=null, 
    @Phone nvarchar (15)=null, 
    @email nvarchar (30)=null, 
    @CompanyName nvarchar (15)=null , 
    @Gender nvarchar (15)=null, 
    @BarthDay date =null, 
    @Question nvarchar (15)=null, 
    @answer nvarchar (100)=null ) 
AS 

if @check = 'a' 
    begin 
        insert into Member values
        (@Check,@UserName,@Passowerd,@Name,@Phone,@email,@CompanyName,@Gender,@BarthDay,@Question,@answer) 
    end

if @Check = 'u'
    begin
        UPDATE Member 
        SET Passowerd = @Passowerd, 
        [Name] = @Name, 
        Phone = @Phone,
        email =@email, 
        CompanyName = @CompanyName, 
        Gender = @Gender, 
        BarthDay = @BarthDay, 
        Question = @Question, 
        Answer = @Answer 
        WHERE (UserName=@UserName) 
    end 

if @check= 'd'
    begin 
        Delete from member 
        where (userName = @userName) 
    end 
return
```

You might want to look at the [MERGE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) statement though.

Answer (score 0):

Try losing the last comma

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.storMember
(
    @Check nchar          (1),
    @UserName nvarchar    (15),
    @Passowerd nvarchar   (15)=null,
    @Name nvarchar        (15)=null,
    @Phone nvarchar       (15)=null,
    @email nvarchar       (30)=null,
    @CompanyName nvarchar (15)=null ,
    @Gender nvarchar      (15)=null,
    @BarthDay date        (15)=null,
    @Question nvarchar    (15)=null,
    @answer nvarchar      (100)=null**,**
)
```

Comment: insert error column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition                                                                         this msg appear when i press Ctrl+s why